# What is the difference between "This is" and "Here is"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-choice

I mean, is there a difference in the meaning, or the contexts for these sentences?

When using the one or the other one?

My question is about every kind of words. Innert things, or beings, or any other cases.

For instance (but not limitative):

> "This/Here is my book."
>   "This/Here is my cat."

Comment: Can you give us a sentence where you'd like to use one of these?

Comment: With any words. This is my book/ Here is my book; This is my cat/ Here is my cat.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker so I would not like to make a formal answer, but there is a clear distinction. For example, you can say like Bon Jovi's song, "This ain't a song for broken hearted". But you would **not** say "Here ain't a song for broken hearted". If you look at this link [ https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/demonstrative-pronouns/ ] you will see the word "here" is not a demonstrative pronoun as Engruoo answered. Okay so what is it? Please help me too :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference.

*This* is a demonstrative pronoun. So, using it you, you specify which cat is yours. For example:

> -There are many cats in this room. Which one is yours?
>
> -Oh, this is my cat. *(pointing at the cat)*

But if you enter a room holding your cat, you might say to your guest, "Here is my cat." It sounds like you are introducing it to your guest.

But you could also say "This is my cat" to your guest. Again, it's like you are pointing at the cat drawing the guest's attention to your pet.

"Here is my cat" can mean emphasis on the place:

> Where is my cat? Oh, *here* is my cat. (talking to yourself finding the cat after looking for the animal for some time)

Comment: But isn't here also the pronoun opposed to the pronoun **there**??

Comment: There is my cat ( the place is unknown ) / Here is my cat ( the place is fixed. )

Comment: @KentaroTomono from the grammatical point of view, "there is my cat" and "here is my cat" are very different sentences. In the first one, "there" is the subject and "my cat" is the object, while in the second sentence the word order is inverted - we could say "my cat is here." But saying "here is my cat" we put more emphasis on "here." "There is my cat" would mean something like "it exists" (e.g. there is love, there is friendship in this world, and, well, there is my cat).

Comment: I would not like to argue about this because this can give me a nice headache, but if you kindly provide us with some sources, I think your answer will be much nicer.

Comment: @KentaroTomono let me just say that if you want to make the sentence "my cat is there" inverted by putting "there" before "it," it may be very confusing, especially if you can't rely on intonation to convey what you mean. It sounds like you are talking about the existence of the cat rather than where it actually is. As for the sources, my answer is based on my knowledge and experience, not on excerpts from grammar books. If I come across something relevant, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @KentaroTomono one last thing. Inversion can happen after "there" when it is as an adverb of place. For example, "She looked out and there was Pamela." In this context it's clear that "there" functions not as a dummy subject. Sorry if I've given you a headache :-) This is an interesting question to answer and discuss, but it's not the same as "this is my cat" vs. "here is my cat." It deserves a separate question.